# App crashes when trying to give microphone permission in Android 11

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-11, runtime-permissions

Working fine in other versions of the app except Android 11. It gives the below Exception

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.connectmyhealth.patient.dev, PID: 14865
    java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
        at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
        at com.connectmyhealth.patient.commons.helper.SoundMeter.start(SoundMeter.java:22)
        at com.connectmyhealth.patient.ui.call.callpermissionsetup.CallPermissionSetupActivity$handleClickEvent$2.onClick(CallPermissionSetupActivity.kt:89)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7559)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7536)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:828)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28699)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7858)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:600)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
```

This is the code for starting MediaPlayer

```
public void start() {
        if (mRecorder == null) {
            mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION);
            mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            mRecorder.setOutputFile("/dev/null");
            try {
                mRecorder.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mRecorder.start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show how are you starting MediaRecorder?

Comment: can you try changing output format to MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB

Comment: Replace `"/dev/null"` with the correct file path `"absolutePath/record.3gp"` and it should work

Comment: did it work for you .im having same issue but i already got rid of /dev/null ..

Comment: @j2emanue just change the output format as  MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB

Comment: tried that. I'm on android 11 and trying to record audio while on a phone call. I just need to detect sound actually. But it seems recording during phone call is no longer allowed. Have you tried. Same code works on android 10

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MediaRecorder Android 11 start failed -1004](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64846610/mediarecorder-android-11-start-failed-1004)

Comment: @AlexKrafts I just changed the output format of MediaRecorder and it worked for me.